# issues of cuBLAS performance on batched complex linear system solver

Tags: cuda, cublas

I am new to cuda and cuBlas, and recently I am trying to use batched cuBlas API to solve multiple systems of linear equations. Here's my code:

The size of the matrix is N, and the number of matrices (batch size) is numOfMat.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>      // deal with complex numbers
#include <cuda_profiler_api.h>
    
using namespace std::chrono;

#define N 6
#define numOfMat 500000
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

int main() {
    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 generator(device());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(1., 5.);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2;
    double duration = 0;
    double duration_1 = 0;

    // step 1: cuda solver initialization
    cublasHandle_t cublas_handle;
    cublasCreate_v2(&cublas_handle);
    cublasStatus_t stat;

    int* PivotArray;
    int* infoArray;
    cudaError_t cudaStatUnified1 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStatUnified2 = cudaSuccess;
    const cuDoubleComplex alpha = make_cuDoubleComplex(1.0f, 0.0f);
    cudaStatUnified1 = cudaMallocManaged(&PivotArray, N * numOfMat * sizeof(int));
    cudaStatUnified2 = cudaMallocManaged(&infoArray, numOfMat * sizeof(int));
    if ((cudaSuccess != cudaStatUnified1) || (cudaSuccess != cudaStatUnified2))
        std::cout <<"unified memory allocated unsuccessful!"<<std::endl;

    //ALLOCATE MEMORY - using unified memory
    cuDoubleComplex** h_A;
    cudaMallocManaged(&h_A, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex*) * numOfMat);
    cudaMallocManaged(&(h_A[0]), sizeof(cuDoubleComplex)*numOfMat*N*N);
    for (int nm = 1; nm < numOfMat; nm++)
        h_A[nm] = h_A[nm-1]+ N * N;

    cuDoubleComplex** h_b;
    cudaMallocManaged(&h_b, sizeof(cuDoubleComplex*) * numOfMat);
    cudaMallocManaged(&(h_b[0]), sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * numOfMat * N);
    for (int nm = 1; nm < numOfMat; nm++)
        h_b[nm] = h_b[nm-1] + N;

    // FILL MATRICES
    for (int nm = 0; nm < numOfMat; nm++)
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
          h_A[nm][j * N + i] = make_cuDoubleComplex(distribution(generator), distribution(generator));

    // FILL COEFFICIENTS
    for (int nm = 0; nm < numOfMat; nm++)
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        h_b[nm][i] = make_cuDoubleComplex(distribution(generator), distribution(generator));

    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // step 2: Perform CUBLAS LU solver
    stat = cublasZgetrfBatched(cublas_handle, N, h_A, N, PivotArray, infoArray, numOfMat);
    if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf ("-data download failed");
    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
    // check if the input matrix is singular
    /*for (int i = 0; i < numOfMat; i++)
      if (infoArray[i] != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Factorization of matrix %d Failed: Matrix may be singular\n", i);
      }*/

    // step 3: INVERT UPPER AND LOWER TRIANGULAR MATRICES
    // --- Function solves the triangular linear system with multiple RHSs
    // --- Function overrides b as a result
    stat = cublasZtrsmBatched(cublas_handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_DIAG_UNIT, N, 1, &alpha, h_A, N, h_b, N, numOfMat);
    if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf ("--data download failed");
    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );

    stat = cublasZtrsmBatched(cublas_handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT, N, 1, &alpha, h_A, N, h_b, N, numOfMat);
    if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf ("---data download failed");
    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );

    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout<<duration<<std::endl;
}
```

The code works fine, but when I plot the computational time versus the number of matrices, the curve looks like this:

[image]

My question is: **why does the computational time show linear to the number of matrices**? Intuitively, the curve should look to be flat when the batch size is large in some extent. However, when the batch size reaches up to 500,000, the time still appears to be linear to the batch size.

How can it be? Is there any explanation behind such a circumstance?

Comment: Intuitively one would expect that the amount of work required to process N matrices is N-times the amount of the work required to process one matrix. Given some hardware capable of doing the work of processing one matrix in time T, we would expect processing time for N matrices to *roughly* grow as N*T, i.e. linear growth. You might want to clarify why you are expecting something different.

Comment: Well, I expect to have a rather flat curve as cuBLAS computes N matrices in parallel! That means, the increase of the number of matrices should not consume the time in a linear manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look more closely at your data. If I run a modification of your code on Google Colab (Tesla T4) I get this:

[image]

Which looks largely like your figure. But look more closely (log scales help):

[image]

You can clearly see that up to a certain point, the runtime is largely independent of the number of matrices (around 2^8 = 64), but then scaling is linear as sizes increase. That is the transition from being able to parallelize the workload to reaching parallel capacity and having to schedule many parallel groups of operations to execute the workload. You might infer that for this particular GPU, the GPU run out of parallel capacity at between 64 and 128 concurrent operations (The T4 has 40 SM, so it might well be 80 if an SM could accommodate 2 operations per SM concurrently), after which runtime scales with multiples of that limiting size.

This is completely normal behaviour for any parallel computation architecture I am familiar with.

Comment: I would expect that for tiny 6x6 matrices as used here, the runtime of small batches will be entirely dominated by the kernel launch time of about 5 microseconds, and a small *initial* portion of the graph would be almost horizontal as a result.

Comment: @njuffa: This is timing his whole code, which includes two calls to cublasZtrsmBatched and that call probably runs multiple kernels, so where the latency/workload transition point is for this case might be hard to pinpoint. But in theory the runtime should be constant until the GPU is "full" and then scale as multiples of that "full" size. I would expect a really detailed run to produce a "staircase" runtime versus problem size graph, but I am not going to go further in this case

Comment: I agree. My comment was not meant to contradict but to *add* another aspect to the answer. A CUBLAS API call composed of multiple extremely short running kernels under the hood will not help alleviate exposure to the issue of basic launch overhead. This has bitten a number of real-life applications in the behind as GPUs have become much faster and kernel execution times shrank accordingly until they were of the same order of magnitude as the launch overhead.